# On public keys compression, why an even or odd y coordinate corresponds to the positive / negative sign respectively?

Tags: public-key

This is a paragraph from Andreas' book on compressed/uncompressed public keys.

*Chapter 4 - Section - Key Formats*

> Whereas uncompressed public keys have a prefix of 04 ,compressed
>   public keys start with either a 02 or a 03 prefix. Let’s look at why
>   there are two possible prefixes: because the left side of the equation
>   is y^2 , that means the solution for y is a square root, which can
>   have a positive or negative value. Visually, this means that the
>   resulting y coordinate can be above the x-axis or below the x-axis. As
>   you can see from the graph of the elliptic curve in Figure 4-2, the
>   curve is symmetric, meaning it is reflected like a mirror by the
>   x-axis. So, while we can omit the y coordinate we have to store the
>   sign of y (positive or negative), or in other words, we have to
>   remember if it was above or below the x-axis because each of those
>   options represents a different point and a different public key. **When
>   calculating the elliptic curve in binary arithmetic on the finite
>   field of prime order p, the y coordinate is either even or odd, which
>   corresponds to the positive/negative sign as explained earlier.**
>   Therefore, to distinguish between the two possible values of y, we
>   store a compressed public key with the prefix 02 if the y is even, and
>   03 if it is odd, allowing the software to correctly deduce the y
>   coordinate from the x coordinate and uncompress the public key to the
>   full coordinates of the point. Public key compression is illustrated
>   in Figure 4-7

What I don't get is that bold text.

Why an even or odd y coordinate corresponds to the positive / negative sign?

For example, are all even public keys below the x-axis?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no such thing as a negative or a positive value when you're talking in a finite field.

For example, in `Z7`, the field of integers modulo `7`. There holds:

- `0` = `7` = `14` = `-7`
- `1` = `8` = `15` = `-6`
- `2` = `9` = `16` = `-5`
- ...

So you can't say that the number `2` is positive, because it's equal to `-5`.

Despite that, the square root still has two solutions. For example, `3^2` = `9` = `2`, `4^2` = `16` = `2`. Thus both `3` and `4` are square roots of `2`.

So we need a way to say which solution we want. Turns out, that when reduced to a range of 0-6, the two solutions of the square, one is odd and the other is even.

Comment: +1 for clarifying that pos & neg are not meaningful in modulo fields

Comment: @Pieter Wuille, i am getting confused with the powers of 2s. I tried the exercise with `y² mod p = (x³ + 7) mod p , for p = 5, x = 3`, i get 2 solutions as you explained, and it happens that you can find the odd/even solution (`2² mod 5 = 3² mod 5`) for `y²`. I had to force this to come up with `2` and `3` as square roots of `4` although it makes sense as the `real` roots are`2` and `-2`, and `-2 mod 5 = 3`. What if `x=4`? We get `1² mod 5` and ... `2.44948974² mod 5`. A fractional number can't be odd or even.

Comment: Square root here does not refer to the classical real square root. It refers to the inverse function of `x^2 mod p`. So we say `y` is the square root of `x mod p` iff `y^2 mod p = x`.

Comment: @PieterWuille  i got it now!!! Thank you. Sorry for my misconception. 
Lastly, why does one need to know if s*2>N at:  `is_high_s = s*2 > N` and   `v = 27 + ((y % 2) ^ (1 if is_high_s else 0))` ?

Comment: Because every number that has a square root has in fact two (negating a number does not change its square). Thus we need a way to convey which of the two square roots is the one meant.

Answer (score 3):

Elliptic curves are of the form y^2 = f(x).

This means there are two roots to the equation. i.e. if we know an x there are two possible y values that satisfy the equation (y & -y). Because we are using a modulo type number field, it happens that the even and odd translate to y and -y

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Prime_or_prime_power_modulus

This confused me too, until I figured out modulo type fields are not as normal as we expect.

Comment: Why not just transmit the y value instead as 2s complement.

Comment: See Pieter's answer above (very good detail). Basically a 2s complement is the modulus of the word size (in bits); so we need to use a Ns complement - where N is the modulus of the field. So a modulus of 2^n - we can use 2s complement